# Add row to drop down menu that comes from a datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down menu that is populated from a database:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="searchApplicationDropDown" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8" DataTextField="AppName" 
        DataValueField="PK_Application"></asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_Application], [AppName] FROM [Application]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How do I add a row at the top manually outside of the database?

Comment: Is this the **default selected row** so that you can be sure they select a value?

Comment: It is the default selected row, which will be used to show they have not selected anything from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `DataBound` event of the dropdown list (which occurs after all of the values from the database have been put into the dropdown list), like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="searchApplicationDropDown" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8" DataTextField="AppName" 
    DataValueField="PK_Application" OnDataBound="searchApplicationDropDown_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void searchApplicationDropDown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;

    if (list != null)
    {
        list.Items.Insert(0, "--Select One--");
    }
}
```

Comment: No. This won't work if the array or dropdownlist has all entries full because of the number of rows from the sqldatasource. You need to hard-code it directly in ASPX to avoid an "out of bounds" error (see Matthew Schaad's response below)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `AppendDataBoundItems` property of `DropDownList` like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList
    ID="searchApplicationDropDown" runat="server"
    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8"
    DataTextField="AppName" 
    DataValueField="PK_Application">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_Application], [AppName] FROM [Application]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just trying to get a default row at the top. One approach would be this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT -1 AS [PK_Application], 'Please select an application...' AS [AppName] UNION ALL SELECT [PK_Application], [AppName] FROM [Application]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm not sure that `[PK_Application]` is an `int`, but you could modify the `SELECT` as necessary to get it to sort. You may even need to modify the `Please select an application...` to be something like `(Please select an application...)` to get it sort right.

Answer (score 1):

Use PreRender

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   searchApplicationDropDown.Items.Insert(0 , new ListItem("Select...", "")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
searchApplicationDropDown.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "", Value = "value" });
```